# What Excel formula do I need here?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet working on that has a list of activities that occurred between January and December and each activity occurred multiple times during January thru December ie: June there were 12 different entries that occurred with one activity occurring multiple times

What I need is to count the number of occurrences of a certain activity but only those occurring in June. I have tried the `count` function, the `sum` function, the `countif` function, the `sumif` function, and the `if` function - nothing is working!

Also I am using 2010 Excel, here is example of my tried equations `=countif(a3:a16,a73,c4,a3:a165)`. The range a3:a165 is data range a73 is date c4 is activity. I am just drawing a blank and have researched it but nothing seems to fit and I haven't used Excel in this form since high school.

Column a is month column c is activity column b is persons name

Comment: I think this would be better on _Super User_, since it is not about programming. That said, I think you might need to supply more information - it feels a bit broad at the moment. (If you can format and paragraph your questions, so they are as readable as possible, it really does help btw - see my edit).

Comment: `CountIf` only take two arguments, as far as I am aware.

Comment: Explore `CountIfs` or `SumProduct`

Comment: You might have to work on a 2 stage solution. That is, id all the items from June first ... pull them over to another column, then do a countif ... at that point, it might be easier to just put a formula in another column : `=if(and(a3="june",c3="activity"), 1, 0)`  then just sum that column up.

Comment: 1. It seems that you have combined the dates and activities into a single column. No function is going to be able to determine the dates without some text parsing. 2. While `COUNTIFS` may be part of the solution, you cannot have criteria ranges of different sizes in it. Either you have a typo in your sample formula or you are breaking the function3. A few rows of redacted sample data would have made this question much easier to understand and resolve.

Comment: No I stayed that column a is month and column c is activity.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `COUNTIFS` it is same as `COUNTIF` but it takes multiple conditions.

Since you didn't specify all relevant ranges I'll assume that A3:a165 has the dates, and B3:B165 has activity names

```
=COUNTIFS(MONTH(A3:A165),Month(a73),B3:B165,C4)
```

So you were almost there. However if this doesn't work for you consider adding column C if possible where you would use following formula(ex. of C3) `=MONTH(A3)` and your `countif` formula would would look like this

```
=COUNTIFS(A3:A165,MONTH(A73),B3:B165,C4)
```

Comment: Column A and Column C are the only columns I need for the formula column b is just names of the people which is not a part of the equation

Comment: Ok but that being said where are the activity names?
Are they in A3:A165 together with dates?

Comment: Column a is month column c is activity